# SQL statement to return grouped nodes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like the one below:

```
nodelabel | ipaddr  | serviceid
x1        | 1.1.1.1 | 1
x1        | 1.1.1.2 | 2
x1        | 1.1.1.3 | 2
x2        | 2.2.2.1 | 1
x2        | 2.2.2.2 | 3
x3        | 3.3.3.1 | 2
x3        | 3.3.3.2 | 3
```

I am trying to write a sql query which return all nodes where the serviceid != 1 where the resulted table should be like (i.e. this is the desired output)

```
nodelabel     | ipaddr  | serviceid
    x3        | 3.3.3.1 | 2
    x3        | 3.3.3.2 | 3
```

I have tried many ways to do so but my attempts are just excluding the nodes where the serviceid != 1 and the resulted table would look like:

```
nodelabel     | ipaddr  | serviceid
    x1        | 1.1.1.2 | 2
    x1        | 1.1.1.3 | 2
    x2        | 2.2.2.2 | 3
    x3        | 3.3.3.1 | 2
    x3        | 3.3.3.2 | 3
```

any thought or help provided is appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain why your desired table has `ipaddr` = 1.1.1.1? What is the logic behind that?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: the database is PostgreSQL.

Comment: IP addresses are chosen randomly with no specific logic behind.

Comment: There is no row in the table having `nodelabel = 'x3'` and `ipaddr = '1.1.1.1'`. What's the logic behind the expected outcome?

Comment: @axiac, sorry was a typing mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you all rows where `nodelabel` doesn't have a value of 1 for `service_id`.  If so, `not exists` should do what you want:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.nodelabel = t.nodelabel and t2.service_id = 1
                 );
```

Comment: `t2.nodelabel - t.nodelabel` should be `t2.nodelabel = t.nodelabel`

Comment: Thank you Gordon. that solved the problem... I was not even thinking of aliasing the tables and using them in the way you showed me.

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(nodelabel CHAR(2) NOT NULL
,ipaddr  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,serviceid INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(nodelabel,ipaddr,serviceid)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('x1','1.1.1.1',1),
('x1','1.1.1.2',2),
('x1','1.1.1.3',2),
('x2','2.2.2.1',1),
('x2','2.2.2.2',3),
('x3','3.3.3.1',2),
('x3','3.3.3.1',3);

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.nodelabel = x.nodelabel 
   AND y.serviceid = 1 
 WHERE y.nodelabel IS NULL;
+-----------+---------+-----------+
| nodelabel | ipaddr  | serviceid |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
| x3        | 3.3.3.1 |         2 |
| x3        | 3.3.3.1 |         3 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: I am working on existing database and tables, do not want to change the structure of them at the moment but thank you for your insight on this.

Comment: I've not changed nuffink